# Cannot convert first element in array to integer using .to_i

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code in my controller:

```
@raw_data = ["124324/12", "345346/15"]
@data_set = []
@raw_data.each do |data| 
    holder = data.split("/")
    holder.first.to_i
    @data_set << holder
end
```

This returns the following

```
[["124324", "12"], ["345346", "15"]]
```

Why has it not converted the first element in each sub array to an integer. Please explain

Comment: Your `holder.first.to_i` is doing nothing meaningful here. It just creates the integer that you want, but is not assigned to any variable, and disappears. `holder` remains intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `to_i` returns the converted value.  It doesn't do an in place conversion.  This means that the value of the variable doesn't change.

```
@raw_data = ["124324/12", "345346/15"]
@data_set = []
@raw_data.each do |data| 
    holder = data.split("/")
    holder[0] = holder.first.to_i
    @data_set << holder
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`holder.first.to_i` return the value cast to an integer but you are not reassigning it.

Try `holder = holder.first.to_i`

Answer (score 2):

`to_i` creating another object and you are inserting old object. you can use `map` without needing variable assignment.

```
@raw_data = ["124324/12", "345346/15"]
@data_set = @raw_data.map do |data|
  d = data.split("/")
  [d[0].to_i, d[1]]
end

p @data_set
# [[124324, "12"], [345346, "15"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`to_i` returns the object parsed as an integer, but it does not change the original object

```
x = "123"
p x # "123"

y = x.to_i
p x # "123"
x.is_a? String # true
p y # 123
y.is_a? Integer # true
```

So in your case, you probably want to change your code to read

```
@raw_data.each do |data| 
  holder = data.split("/")
  @data_set << holder.first.to_i
end
```